# How the loop - for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){ for(j=1;j<=i;j++){ }} works in making a butterfly pattern using C++ language?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Program code for butterfly pattern-`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    // Upper part of the butterfly
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // Print stars
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }

        // Print spaces
        int space = 2 * (n - i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= space; j++) {
            cout << " ";
        }

        // Print stars for the second set
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    // Lower part of the butterfly
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        // Print stars
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }

        // Print spaces
        int space = 2 * (n - i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= space; j++) {
            cout << " ";
        }

        // Print stars
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output -
[Butterfly pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXDSP.jpg)

After executing the above code we will get output as

```
4


*      *


**    **


***  ***


********


********


***  ***


**    **


*      *
```

Here if we consider the column no. we can see that

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 - col no. 

 1 *             *
 2 * *         * *
 3 * * *     * * *
 4 * * * * * * * *
 5 * * * * * * * *
 6 * * *     * * *
 7 * *         * *
 8 *             *
 |
 row no.
```

See in this according to column no. the condition is not satisfied as when the value of j is 5 in second part of the upper pattern it is not satisfying the condition of j<=i as the value of i is 4 there.
But the output is showing the correct pattern.Then how this for loop works here ?

Comment: Sorry pattern is not correctly visible in the text part but you can see the pattern in the image

Comment: We can see in the image that there are 8 rows(i) and 8 columns (j).

Comment: In the upper part of the pattern after the space if we will choose j=5 then it will be greater than i=4. Then how the loop is working?

Comment: `j` always starts at 1, it doesn't assume the row number. Rows are numbered `1` to `n` inclusive and then `n` to `1` inclusive in reverse. Basically the lower half is done exactly the same as the top half.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to improve formatting and other things.

Comment: As for understanding the code, I suggest you step through the code line by line using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), while writing down all details, and the output, using pen and paper.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Side note: Loops like `for(int i = 1; i <= max; ++i)` have a bit of a smell in C++ – unless you want to output one-based indices for some reason you should rather prefer `for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)` – note the shift by 1 towards zero – this is especially relevant if you iterate over arrays this way, as with one-based loop you'd skip very first entry in the array and end up in undefined bahaviour on accessing `array[std::size(array)]`.

Comment: If you are outputting single characters anyway you should rather prefer *character literals* (`'*'`, `' '`, `'\n'`) – this is more efficient as the implementation doesn't need to look up the end of the string.

Comment: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)…

Comment: In those loops, `j` is not a column number. It's merely a counter. The code for the upper half says "print `i` stars, then `2*(n-i)` spaces, then `i` more stars".

Comment: @RuparnaChakraborty Why did you tag this as `design-patterns`?

Comment: Thank you all.... Now I understood the concept 